# How can I run fixture in concurrent mode but test inside fixture in sequential mode in Testcafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have 5 fixtures with 10 tests in each fixture. How can I run 5 fixtures in the concurrent mode in 5 different browser instances, but I need tests inside each fixture run sequentially. A result of the test execution I need into a single report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test parallelization works in the following way:

- calculates the full test count
- runs the defined count of browser instances
- calculates the portion of tests for each browser instance and runs it

So, it's impossible to guarantee that test portion for each browser will contain tests from only one fixture.

See also: [Run Tests Concurrently](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/run-tests.html#run-tests-concurrently).

Comment: Thank you for clarification